# Radial and angular part of the space of compactly supported smooth functions

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

On page 124 of Thaller's *The Dirac equation* the following space is mentioned :
$$C^{\infty}_0(0, \infty)\otimes C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^2)\subset L^2(0, \infty)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{S}^2),$$
where the symbol $\otimes$ refers to Hilbert space tensor product (cfr. Reed & Simon vol.I section II.4). Precisely, the author claims that $C_0^{\infty}(0, \infty)\otimes C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is the image of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{o\})$ under the unitary mapping

\begin{array} 
 \.L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) &\to& L^2(0, \infty)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{S}^2) \\
\psi(x, y,z)&\mapsto& r \psi(r\sin \theta\cos\phi, r \sin \theta\sin \phi, r\cos\theta).
\tag{U}\end{array}

**Problem**

The construction of Hilbert space tensor product involves taking a completion and so, if I'm not mistaken, it must be

$$C_0^{\infty}(0, \infty)\otimes C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^2)=L^2(0, \infty)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{S}^2). $$

So something is wrong. Am I mistaken? If not, what is the correct image of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{o\})$ under the mapping (U)?

Thank you.